# Angular 6: Directive with element selector not constructed when element is created by an external custom element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have a directive with an `img` selector that is intended to manipulate the attributes of all img element instances in the document:

```
import { Directive,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageProcessorService } from './imageProcessor.service';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img' // all img tags encountered throughout the app
})
export class ImgElementDirective {
  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef,
      private imageProcessorService: ImageProcessorService) {
    this.imageProcessorService.processImage(this.elementRef);
  }
}
```

This directive is declared under app.module.ts as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ImgElementDirective
  ],
```

I'm by far not an Angular expert, but my understanding is that an instance of the above directive is constructed for every img encountered in the document.

This approach works for any img tags located in Angular markup. My application, however, employs the use of several StencilJS components that also produce img tags. However, `this.imageProcessorService.processImage` is not called for such instances.

I'm assuming that this behavior is due to the fact that Angular is not aware of externally created img elements. Is there a workaround to get around this behavior? Perhaps I'm missing something or otherwise doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `an instance of the above directive is constructed for every img encountered in the document.` ?  This is interesting if its true

Comment: @OwenKelvin i remember reading that somewhere, but it makes sense to me because an `elementRef` is passed into the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the following way.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive(
    { selector: 'img' }
)
export class ImageLazyLoadingDirective extends Directive implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>) {
        super();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const img = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        if ('loading' in HTMLImageElement.prototype) {
          img.setAttribute('loading', 'lazy');
          console.log('>>> loading lazy is supported!');
        } else {
          console.log('>>> loading lazy is NOT supported!');
        }
    }
}
```